# Head of a simple linked list changing

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

Hello guys I am trying linked list implementation in C language

I do by so In my linked_list.h file I have

```
struct Node{
    void *data;
    struct Node *next;
};
struct LinkedList{
    struct Node* head;
};
```

And its implementation linked_list.c

```
struct LinkedList* Create_linked_list(){
    struct LinkedList* linked_list = (struct LinkedList*)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
    return linked_list;
}

struct Node* Get_last_node(struct LinkedList* linked_list){
    struct Node *temp = linked_list->head;
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next; 
    }

    return temp;
}

struct Node* Get_node_at(struct LinkedList* linked_list,int position){
    if(position >= get_size(linked_list)){
        return NULL;
    }else{
        struct Node *temp = linked_list->head;
        int i;
        for(i=0;i< position;i++){
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        return temp;
    }
}

void Append_node(struct LinkedList* linked_list,void *data){
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if(linked_list->head == NULL){
        linked_list->head = new_node;
    }else{
        struct Node *last_node = Get_last_node(linked_list);
        last_node->next = new_node;
    }   
}

int get_size(struct LinkedList* linked_list){
    struct Node* temp = linked_list->head;
    int length;
    while(temp != NULL){
        length++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return length;
}


void Delete_linked_list(struct LinkedList* linked_list){
    free(linked_list->head);
    free(linked_list);
}
```

and in my main.c

```
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    struct LinkedList *linked_list = Create_linked_list();

    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        Append_node(linked_list,(void*)&i);
    }
    struct Node *node_n = Get_node_at(linked_list,1);
    printf("%d\n",*(int*)node_n->data);

    Delete_linked_list(linked_list);
    return 0;
}
```

I have two questions:

1) I get the output as 11
   It means that the head is changing in the recursion.
   What is the reason for this?

2)Is it necessary to free the memory by

```
free(linked_list->head);
  free(linked_list);
```

or only `free(linked_list);` is sufficient?

Comment: The output is 11 because you are inserting the same pointer into every node, and they all point to `&i`, which ends up at value `11` after the for loop.  If you wanted to store the integers 1..10 into the linked list, you would need to dereference the pointer you passed in, instead of just storing the pointer.

Comment: @JS1 I did not get this line need to dereference the pointer you passed in

Comment: But I want store not only `int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The output is 11 because you are inserting the same pointer into every node, and they all point to &i, which ends up at value 11 after the for loop. If you wanted to store the integers 1..10 into the linked list, you would need to cast your integers to void *.  Here is your `main()` function rewritten to do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    struct LinkedList *linked_list = Create_linked_list();

    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=10;i++){
        // Notice: store integer casted to void *
        Append_node(linked_list,(void*)(intptr_t) i);
    }
    struct Node *node_n = Get_node_at(linked_list,1);
    // Notice: cast the void * back to integer.
    printf("%d\n", (int)(intptr_t) node_n->data);

    Delete_linked_list(linked_list);
    return 0;
}
```

As for the question of deletion, not only do you need to free `linked_list` and `linked_list->head`, you also need to free every node in the linked list, otherwise you will be leaking memory.

```
void Delete_linked_list(struct LinkedList* linked_list){
    struct Node *p = linked_list->head;

    while (p != NULL) {
        struct Node *next = p->next;
        free(p);
        p = next;
    }

    free(linked_list);
}
```

Comment: Thanks,But I am getting this warning  `warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size`

Comment: @Goutam I modified my casts to include an additional cast to `intptr_t`, which is always the same size as a pointer.  Try again with the new code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `create` function should be like:

```
struct LinkedList* Create_linked_list(){
    struct LinkedList* linked_list = malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));
    return linked_list;
}
```

See what I've changed. You don't want to allocate memory for a pointer but for the whole structure so, it should be `malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));`

And if you want a function to insert a node (I think you are doing it with your append), you should insert in the head like:

```
void insertnode (struct LinkedList* linked_list, void *data){
    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = linked_list->head;
    linked_list->head = new_node;
}
```

And for your delete function:

```
void Delete_linked_list(struct LinkedList* linked_list){
    if(linked_list->head->next){
        Delete_linked_list(linked_list->next);
    }
    else{
       free(linked_list->head);
    }
}
```